# Convert and call an C++ STDCALL to C#

Tags: c#, c++, struct

I have this C++ code definition:

```
static void STDCALL HandleVideoStatic(PVOID pContext, BYTE * apData[3], VideoSampleInfo_T * pVSI)
{
    ((TMediaCallbackHandler *)pContext)->HandleVideo(apData, pVSI);
}
```

And it's passed to an method ( without initializing )

```
WD_RegisterVideoPreviewCB(m_ahChannels[i], &m_aMediaHandler[i], HandleVideoStatic);
```

How to convert above HandleVideoStatic to C# code. And how to call it in C# ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have pointers for all 3 objects you need to pass to the function, you can declare it like this:

```
[DllImport("YOUR.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern void HandleVideoStatic(IntPtr pContext, IntPtr apData, IntPtr pVSI);
```

See [Using the DllImport Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for details.

Comment: In C# the m_aMediaHandler[i] is a class instance. If I pass it to IntPtr apData.  VS show an error "invalid agruments". I think because i passed an class instance, not a pointer. But i have to pass an class instance to that place. :( Could you suggest me more ?

Comment: So you have a class in C#? You can't pass that to a C++ method. You need to initiate the corresponding C++ class first (in C++), aquire the pointer of that object and then pass it to the method.

Comment: How do i make a pointer to class instance and pass it to the place ? I thing that instance's pointer will slove the problem.

I'm new to C#, so i can do all the ideas. Sorry about it. THanks you very much.

Comment: Essentially you need to export another C++ function that creates the class instance for you and returns the pointer...I guess you should talk to the person who wrote the C++ code to help you with this.